# Unable to make Applications folder writeable in Mac

Tags: chmod

My Vuze cannot update itself as it claims that my application folder is not writeable.

I tried to make it writeable by

```
chmod 777 /Applications
```

I get the following error

```
$chmod 777 /Applications/
chmod: /Applications/: Operation not permitted
```

**How can you make /Applications folder writeable?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your account has admin privileges, try:

```
 $sudo chmod 777 /Applications
```

And then enter your password.

The danger that starblue mentioned is that by doing this, you are allowing essentially any user on your system full and complete read/write/execute access to your Applications folder.

I hope it's apparent why this is normally, probably a bad idea, that you know what you're doing, etc. etc.

Edited to further add: if you just want to give yourself write access, you're probably much better off with:

```
 $sudo chmod u+w /Applications
```

rather than granting everyone complete access.

Comment: Eh, I figured, "Who am I to presume he doesn't know what he's doing?"

Answer (score 2):

You're likely not root, and as such cannot modify that directory.

If you really, *really* want to do this, add 'sudo' in front of your command, that will give the run of the command root access.

Whether you really need to do this, that's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

On OS X, users can typically add or delete apps from the Applications folder, but can't modify apps. Depending on the app that's trying to update itself, you may be able to delete it, or you could chmod -R u+w the app bundle itself. You wouldn't want to do it for the whole Applications directory, though.

Answer (score 0):

sudo chmod -R 755 /directory

or to make it for all users: 777

Be careful doing this though..

Answer (score -2):

Try running the Disk Utility's Repair Permissions button.

Comment: It has nothing to do with "Repairing permissions". He's account does not have privileges to chmod the Applications directory. That's the issue.